# Subsonic FetchByParameter versus Query

Tags: subsonic

I am getting some memory errors when I attempt to pull back approx 150,000 or more rows into my collection using subsonic. Currently, I am getting an out of memory error when this occurs. Upon further review and debugging I am noticing that the following line seems to be the culprit of the error:

```
OrdersCollection orders = new OrdersCollection();
orders.Load(Orders.FetchByParameter(Orders.Columns.OrderID, order.OrderID));
```

I am wondering if `FetchByParameter` is the correct method I need to be using or if I need to possibly change that to the SubSonic.Query approach.

I have not been able to find any articles or posting with this issue so any help in the matter will be appreciated.

Comment: I have basic idea of subsonic. But why in the world, you would want to pull 150K records in memory? I guess, there should be some way to lazy load the collection.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of this lazy load method so that I amy further understand your suggestion?